# Knockout JS Observable Value Set

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

```
                var sides = self.lines()[self.systemMV.EditableIndex()].Sides();
                for (var i = 0; i < sides.length; i++) {
                    var sash =sides[i].Sashes();
                    for (var j = 0; j < sash.length; j++) {
                        alert(sash[j].GlassStockID());
                        sash[j].GlassStockID(gls.StockID);
                        alert(sash[j].GlassStockID());
                    }
                }
```

I got a code like that. I have a knockout observable named '' self.lines() '' i want to change value on sub value on this observable, let's say this subValue. This subValue in the self.lines().Sides() -> Sashes() -> GlassStockID(newValue). I tried too many roads but it's not working. It's always gets old value of GlassStockID. What am I missing in this code? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzvHa.jpg)

Comment: what if you use console.log() instead of alert() ? btw. is slides is an observableArray? There is no such thing a sub-observables, so i wonder where the GlassStockID function is defined and if it realy sets the value

Comment: first thank you for answer, I solved the problem with global variable definition. I take the value as a new global variable and then just set the value where i need. Can't handle to assing in observableArray but solved from another way.